# Spark --- zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-zookeeper, spark-submit

I am trying to load Json in to hbase using the following command

```
spark-shell --master local[*] --jars ./library/ejml-0.23.jar,library/jollyday.jar,library/protobuf.jar,library/stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar,library/stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models.jar,library/stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar,library/spark-corenlp-0.1.jar,library/target/scala-2.10/dlrl-library_2.10-1.0.jar,library/json4s.jar --driver-memory 5G -i $FILE_PATH
```

The filepath points to source file which contains the logic for the parsing json and loading data into Hbase.
However when the Spark-shell starts up it throws a continuous error in the following way

```
17/12/27 18:20:17 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)

    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)

    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)

17/12/27 18:20:17 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)

    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)

    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)

    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Please help me rectify this issue

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not starting Zookeeper in your localhost:2181 ... Are you using Kafka or some other framework that takes Zookeeper as the registry ?